# Connect4 minimax algorithm makes stupid moves

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I'm trying to implement an algorithm that would choose the optimal next move for the game of Connect 4. As I just want to make sure that the basic **minimax** works correctly, I am actually testing it like a Connect 3 on a 4x4 field. This way I don't need the alpha-beta pruning, and it's more obvious when the algorithm makes a stupid move.

The problem is that the algorithm **always** starts the game with the leftmost move, and also during the game it's just very stupid. It doesn't see the best moves.

I have thoroughly tested methods `makeMove()`, `undoMove()`,  `getAvailableColumns()`, `isWinningMove()` and `isLastSpot()` so I am absolutely **sure** that the problem is not there.

Here is my algorithm.

**NextMove.java**

```
private static class NextMove {
    final int evaluation;
    final int moveIndex;

    public NextMove(int eval, int moveIndex) {
        this.evaluation = eval;
        this.moveIndex = moveIndex;
    }

    int getEvaluation() {
        return evaluation;
    }

    public int getMoveIndex() {
        return moveIndex;
    }
}
```

**The Algorithm**

```
private static NextMove max(C4Field field, int movePlayed) {
    // moveIndex previously validated

    // 1) check if moveIndex is a final move to make on a given field
    field.undoMove(movePlayed);

    // check
    if (field.isWinningMove(movePlayed, C4Symbol.BLUE)) {
        field.playMove(movePlayed, C4Symbol.RED);
        return new NextMove(BLUE_WIN, movePlayed);
    }
    if (field.isWinningMove(movePlayed, C4Symbol.RED)) {
        field.playMove(movePlayed, C4Symbol.RED);
        return new NextMove(RED_WIN, movePlayed);
    }
    if (field.isLastSpot()) {
        field.playMove(movePlayed, C4Symbol.RED);
        return new NextMove(DRAW, movePlayed);
    }

    field.playMove(movePlayed, C4Symbol.RED);

    // 2) moveIndex is not a final move
    // --> try all possible next moves
    final List<Integer> possibleMoves = field.getAvailableColumns();
    int bestEval = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int bestMove = 0;
    for (int moveIndex : possibleMoves) {           
        field.playMove(moveIndex, C4Symbol.BLUE);

        final int currentEval = min(field, moveIndex).getEvaluation();
        if (currentEval > bestEval) {
            bestEval = currentEval;
            bestMove = moveIndex;
        }

        field.undoMove(moveIndex);
    }

    return new NextMove(bestEval, bestMove);
}

private static NextMove min(C4Field field, int movePlayed) {
    // moveIndex previously validated

    // 1) check if moveIndex is a final move to make on a given field
    field.undoMove(movePlayed);

    // check
    if (field.isWinningMove(movePlayed, C4Symbol.BLUE)) {
        field.playMove(movePlayed, C4Symbol.BLUE);
        return new NextMove(BLUE_WIN, movePlayed);
    }
    if (field.isWinningMove(movePlayed, C4Symbol.RED)) {
        field.playMove(movePlayed, C4Symbol.BLUE);
        return new NextMove(RED_WIN, movePlayed);
    }
    if (field.isLastSpot()) {
        field.playMove(movePlayed, C4Symbol.BLUE);
        return new NextMove(DRAW, movePlayed);
    }

    field.playMove(movePlayed, C4Symbol.BLUE);

    // 2) moveIndex is not a final move
    // --> try all other moves
    final List<Integer> possibleMoves = field.getAvailableColumns();
    int bestEval = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int bestMove = 0;
    for (int moveIndex : possibleMoves) {
        field.playMove(moveIndex, C4Symbol.RED);

        final int currentEval = max(field, moveIndex).getEvaluation();
        if (currentEval < bestEval) {
            bestEval = currentEval;
            bestMove = moveIndex;
        }

        field.undoMove(moveIndex);
    }

    return new NextMove(bestEval, bestMove);
}
```

The idea is that the algorithm takes in the arguments of a `currentField` and the `lastPlayedMove`. Then it checks if the last move somehow finished the game. If it did, I just return that move, and otherwise I go in-depth with the subsequent moves.

Blue player is MAX, red player is MIN.

In each step I first undo the last move, because it's easier to check if the "next" move will finish the game, than check if the current field is finished (this would require to analyze for all possible winning options in the field). After I check, I just redo the move.

From some reason this doesn't work. I am stuck with that for days! I have no idea what's wrong... Any help greatly appreciated!